# Доступ к следующему элементу в ForEach в SwiftUI

Tags: swift, циклы, foreach, swiftui

У меня есть цикл, который проходится по всем элементам массива:

```
ForEach(messages, id: \.id) { message in
    // Что-то происходит
}
```

Можно ли как-то в таком случае получить доступ к следующему элементу и его полям (а-ля `message.next.property`), не работая с индексами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

- использовать расширение для массива (взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45340537/3004003))

```
extension BidirectionalCollection where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    typealias Element = Self.Iterator.Element

    func after(_ item: Element, loop: Bool = false) -> Element? {
        if let itemIndex = self.firstIndex(of: item) {
            let lastItem: Bool = (index(after:itemIndex) == endIndex)
            if loop && lastItem {
                return self.first
            } else if lastItem {
                return nil
            } else {
                return self[index(after:itemIndex)]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func before(_ item: Element, loop: Bool = false) -> Element? {
        if let itemIndex = self.firstIndex(of: item) {
            let firstItem: Bool = (itemIndex == startIndex)
            if loop && firstItem {
                return self.last
            } else if firstItem {
                return nil
            } else {
                return self[index(before:itemIndex)]
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Пример структуры

```
struct Message: Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
}
```

Тогда получим например

```
ForEach(messages, id: \.id) { message in
    Text(self.messages.after(message, loop: true)!.text)
}
```

**Вариант 2**

- сделать свою реализацию linked list ([пример](https://www.raywenderlich.com/947-swift-algorithm-club-swift-linked-list-data-structure))

Тогда будут такие изменения

```
class Message: Equatable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text: String
    weak var previous: Message?
    var next: Message?

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    // MARK: Equatable

    static func == (lhs: Message, rhs: Message) -> Bool {
        lhs.text == rhs.text
    }
}
```

При этом нужно будет каким-либо способом присвоить значения переменным `next` и `previous`, например как показано ниже (здесь мы тоже используем расширение)

```
struct ContentView: View {

    let messages = [Message(text: "1"), Message(text: "2"), Message(text: "3"), Message(text: "4")]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(getLinkedMessages(), id: \.id) { message in
                Text("\(message.previous!.text), \(message.text), \(message.next!.text)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getLinkedMessages() -> [Message] {
        messages.map {
            $0.previous = messages.before($0, loop: true)
            $0.next = messages.after($0, loop: true)
            return $0
        }
    }
}
```